# Is it possible to use system restore to a time point before upgrading to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8, is it possible to "restore" to Windows 7 by running system restore in Windows 8 and selecting a restore point prior to upgrading?

Comment: Windows 8 has a different kernel which means the old one is overwritten. I doubt that it will be possible to automatically downgrade the OS version. The Backup feature of the Windows is tracing the configuration changes of the OS and some of the most important files - not the kernel itself i'm afraid. On the side note - i would never risk such a downgrade. The number of people who would try something like that from the statistical point of view provides a conclusion that Windows developers would rather risk a failure than make an effort to satisfy the need of 0.001 percent of users. Ugly truth

Comment: @MichaelTsang - No.  System restore points created within Windows 7 cannot be accessed after an upgrade to Windows 8.  You would need a third-party image of the hdd to acomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are dozens of reasons why this couldn't possibly work.

This is just completely out of scope for the job system restore is designed to do. It would require keeping an entire image of every OS file and everything dependent on OS files on the disk. It would require preserving things like application executables and libraries. It would require some way to connect snapshots taken from one OS with snapshots taken from another.

This really is like trying to use a jackhammer to get demons out of someone's head. There's just no connection whatsoever between what the tool is designed to do and the effect you are trying to get. It just makes no sense whatsoever -- a total non-starter.